# Compact submanifolds of flag manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

This  might be a standard result, but I don't see how to prove or disprove the following: Any connected compact submanifold of a complex flag manifold is itself a complex flag manifold.

I was thinking that this submanifold could be real, but the thing is that complex flag manifolds are defined by real Lie groups!

Comment: For any manifold M, you can embed it in some $R^n$. So take a flag manifold of dimension > n,   and take any open ball in it that's diffeomorphic to $R^m$ , m > n, and you can embed your manifold in it. Maybe this isn't what you are asking?

Comment: So flag manifolds can be defined as $G/H$ where G is a compact lie group and $H$ is the centralizer of a torus. My question is: Is any compact submanifold of $G/H$ is a flag manifold?

Comment: My point is that every compact manifold can be embedded into some flag manifold. So equivalently you are asking if there is some compact, connected manifold which is not a flag manifold.

Comment: There are a vast, vast number of manifolds (in dimension 3 the classification is wildly complicated and only in some sense a 'classification'; in dimension 4 you can naturally make a manifold whose fundamental group is given by your choice of finitely presented group, and the structure of manifolds with fixed fundamental group is itself complicated; it only gets more complicated from here). Furthermore, as Lorenzo explains well, every $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ embeds into any manifold $N$ of dimension $2n$ or larger, by first embedding $M$ into $\Bbb R^{2n}$ and then by including in a chart

Comment: I see your points. Thanks